# What is a sufficient condition for stable convergence of a variable coefficient partial differential equation solution solved by the FDM?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences, stability-theory

While studying the finite difference method for solving partial differential equations, I came across [this](https://www.iitg.ac.in/gtm/files/chap2.pdf) chapter of a book. On the first paragraph of page $2.27$ it says that the Von Neumann stability condition is only a necessary but not a sufficient condition for stable convergence of a variable coefficient partial differential equation solution. It did not say what is the sufficient condition.

When trying to solve a partial differential equation by using the finite difference method, what is the sufficient condition for stable convergence of a variable coefficient partial differential equation solution?

Comment: Look up "lax equivalence principle".

Comment: Thank you very much :D